# web notification on azure blob static website

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, onesignal

I have a static website using azure storage:

```
https://helloweb.blob.core.windows.net/content/index.html
```

What is the domain I need to configure at onesiganl app settings:

**Site URL** : `https://helloweb.blob.core.windows.net`

**Default Notification Icon URL:** `https://helloweb.blob.core.windows.net/content/icon.png`

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Hello Web",
  "short_name": "Helloweb",
  "start_url": "/content/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "gcm_sender_id": "482941778795"
}

I can't see any user at onesignal users page.
```

Comment: can you explain more on what type of notification are you expecting from where the notifcation event is triggered etc ?

Comment: web push notification. https://helloweb.blob.core.windows.net/content/index.html is where I want to receive the notification.

Comment: have you followed the steps in onesignal web push setup ? also GCM is for android right and for web you have something like "safari_web_id".  also the url that you shared is not opening ( maybe u put it for illustration purpose only and actual url is different)

Comment: The website is https://helloweb.blob.core.windows.net/content/index.html

Comment: Looks like you have fixed it. I could see the hello page and also the notifcation on the bottom right corner .

Comment: But the onesignal all users page show no user, so I cant send a test notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134573/discussion-between-aravind-and-alvin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to onesignal [document](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https) mentioned that **OneSignalSDKWorker.js & OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js** should be served from the **top-level root**. 
In the Azure storage, we **are not able to** set the blob in the **top-level root**. The blobs require a container.

> Upload the files to the **top-level root** of your site directory. The following URLs should be publicly accessible:
>
> • https://yoursite.com/manifest.json
>
> • https://yoursite.com/OneSignalSDKWorker.js
>
> • https://yoursite.com/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js

> OneSignalSDKWorker.js & OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js
>
> • These files should not be renamed and the files should be served from the top-level root

From my experience ,it is not a good choice that put the website in the Azure storage. We could use azure [WebApp service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-overview) to do that easily. I do a test for it. It works correctly.

The following is my detail steps:

1.Create WebApp from the Azure portal

[image]

2.Configure OnSignal settings

[image]

3.Download the [Web Push SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https) and follow the [tutorials](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https) to edit the manifest file.

4.Add an index file and just need to replace the "YOUR APP ID"

```
  <head>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
      <script>
        var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(["init", {
          appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
          autoRegister: false,
          notifyButton: {
            enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
          }
        }]);
      </script>
    </head>
```

5.Upload the code into WebApp using Kudu (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsite.net/).We can drag files into the folder directly. More deploy please refer to official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy).

[image]

[image]

6. From the Firefox browser visit https://yoursite.azurewebsite.net/index.html. And we need to set permission to set the message popup.

[image]

7. Check from [All User] we will see the subscribed user info

[image]